# Postgis ST_DIstance query returning inaccurate results

Tags: database, postgresql, google-maps, geospatial, postgis

I am using the following query to retrieve records from a postgresql DB

```
@services = Service.select("*, ST_Distance(services.lon_lat, ST_GeomFromText('POINT (lat lon)', 4326)) as st_distance").order("st_distance").limit(10)
```

- services.lon_lat is a geography type

After implementing a "get directions" aspect to my app I have noticed a inaccuracy in the distances returned from the above query and the directions in google maps.

It's important to note I did expect a slight discrepancy taking into account the roads to the destination may not be a straight line but it seems the inaccuracy is the other way, for example the 1st returned item in this query says its **216km** away where google maps says **181km**, the 10th says **247km** compared to google maps **203km**...the further the distance the larger the inaccuracy...the 46th item returned if I choose to return that many says **424km** compared to **298km**.

Any guidance or help on this subject would be very much appreciated...

EXAMPLE of coordinates being used Lat: 53.199426 Lon:-8.132368 are in DB and I'm requesting distance from Lat:53.300929 Lon:-6.179949 ... this is the 216km with query and 181km with google

Comment: Have a look here. I wouldn't assume that Google is correct... http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62044/st-distance-is-not-delivering-right-results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The POINT coordinates are in the order longitude, latitude.

This:

```
@services = Service.select("*, ST_Distance(services.lon_lat, ST_GeomFromText('POINT (lat lon)', 4326)) as st_distance").order("st_distance").limit(10)
```

Should be:

```
@services = Service.select("*, ST_Distance(services.lon_lat, ST_GeomFromText('POINT (lon lat)', 4326)) as st_distance").order("st_distance").limit(10)
```